# ASP.NET MVC 5 'DateTime' cannot be saved on sql server 'datetime' format on Release (published) mode but works on Debug mode

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime, entity-framework-6, release

So I have an ASP.NET MV5 app, I'm using Entity Framework 6 and a SQL Server database. I also use this: [datepicker](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/blue-themed-date-picker-date-range-and-week-number-61366925)

I have bootstrap-datepicker input with this format: `'dd.mm.yyyy'`. With jQuery I get this field's value, which is exactly like this `"29.01.2022"` and I send it to an ASP.NET MVC action method which expects a `DateTime` parameter.

On my action that parameter is converted automatically to `DateTime` format but keeps the correct date.

Datepicker configuration:

```
$(".input-daterange") {
   language: 'ro',
   format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',// this gives 29.01.2022
   //format: 'dd.MM.yyyy',// this gives 29.Jan.2022
   autoclose: true,
   calendarWeeks: true,
   clearbtn: true,
   disableTouchKeyboard: true
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework 6 for database access, so my code looks something like this:

```
public Action SaveField(int rowId, DateTime fieldDateValue)
{
    var itemToUpdate = _context.TableName.Single(i => i.id = rowId);    // this is not null
    itemToUpdate.StartDate = fieldDateValue;

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges()
    }
    catch
    { ... }
}
```

This code works well in debug mode but when I publish the app all gets crazy, I get an error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

What I've tried so far (because of datepicker format: `dd.mm.yyyy`):

1. `itemToUpdate.StartDate = fieldDateValue`
2. `itemToUpdate.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fieldDateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))`    --> this worked for a few times but the saved date in the database was from `29.01.2022` to `2022-29-01` so something like `yyyy-MM-dd`, but gives be error too
3. `itemToUpdate.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fieldDateValue.ToString(), "dd.mm.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
4. `itemToUpdate.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fieldDateValue.ToShortDateString(), "dd.mm.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

I simply cannot understand what am I doing wrong giving the fact that the published version of the app I'm running on a remote server (which might explain issues) but also on the same machine (IIS wwroot).

Can someone tell how to correctly manage the date format so there will be no more problems and differences between debug and release versions?

Comment: "var itemToUpdate = _context.TableName.Single(i => i.id = rowId);/// this is not null" Are you sure this is true in release? Seems easy enough to use SingleOrDefault, and null check the itemToUpdate before you do the value reassignment and save changes.

Comment: @AndyStagg yes I'm sure, I didn't wanna write too much but I'm positive it's not null

Comment: The column in the table is a `datetime` column, so it won't get stored in some format like `29.01.2022`. I strongly recommend you teach your jQuery datepicker to not be stupid, and pass an unambiguous format like `yyyyMMdd` to the database. Anything else is unsafe.

Comment: When parsing a date yourself, you need MM (uppercase) for month. Lowercase mm is minute

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes, I think I got I now, I'm testing some things -I was using that "dd.mm.yyyy" on other page and it worked there , but now I've  realized that month was turned to 01(Jan) whatever month I selected from picker

Answer (score -1):

So, finally, what actually worked for published version of my app was this:

1. `date` format in SQL Server database (`datetime` not working)
2. made my filed in `ViewModel` as 'string' instead of `DateTime`
3. `DateTime.ParseExact(fieldDateValue, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`
4. Build -> Clean project then Publish it (just for safety, when you do a lot of publishing) -> this also solves publish failures with Visual Studio 2015 (first time fail than second get's published)
5. Also for failed publishing, last solution is to delete `obj` folder from project

For some reason `DateTime.ParseExact(fieldDateValue.ToShortDateString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` didn't work in release mode

Comment: Why do you insist on using an invalid and ambiguous format? This is _not_ a good solution IMHO, it's more like one of those duct tape jobs on [there I fixed it](https://failblog.cheezburger.com/thereifixedit).

Comment: @AaronBertrand because time is not on my side and I don't know what else to try, it simply doesn't work with DateTime expected viewModel after publishing.

Comment: Ah, you’ve discovered the perfect recipe for technical debt. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯